# IIS 6.0 - 404.0 - Win32 status 3 - but file is present

Tags: iis-6, http-status-code-404

I am booting a PXE image via TFTP and getting an error that I cannot resolve. Basically, upon the image booting, it is supposed to download a configuration file with the extension ".txt" from the same server that it got its image from. It's loading the image fine, but it will not download the config file. When I use the shell to browse to the folder where the config file is supposed to be located, there is a .tmp file. Opening it with notepad shows an HTML 404 page.

The home directory is "C:\Root." The file that needs to be downloaded is "C:\Root\Configs\config.txt." The log file shows the 404 on a GET request for "/Root/Configs/config.txt."

In the IIS log, I am showing a GET request from the client for that file, and it is throwing a 404.0 error with Win32 status 3, both indicating the the file is not found. However, when I browse on the server to that file, it is there, and the path is correct. I have checked the home directory as well, and compared all of the settings against another IIS instance running the same system, and I can't figure out what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific windows error is: "The system cannot find the path specified".  Are you sure the resulting path points to a directory that exists?

Comment: Yes, I checked several times, hoping the solution would be that simple. The home directory is "C:\Root." The file that needs to be downloaded is "C:\Root\Configs\config.txt." The log file shows the 404 on a GET request for "/Root/Configs/config.txt." Unless I'm missing something in the structure, I believe the shell is looking at the right spot on the server, and I've browsed to the path and can see the file is there.

Comment: if the home directory is C:\Root, then the relative file path is /configs/config.txt, not /root/configs/config.txt.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I realized that after I typed out that comment. I fixed the path and it loaded the files without incident. If you'd like to leave that as an answer, I'll modify the question to reflect that detail and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What's the extension of the file that's giving 404? Make sure you add it to the MIME types in IIS, since IIS will, by default, serve a 404 for any file extensions you haven't configured there (it's a security feature, I think). Right click the server node in IIS Manager, choose Properties, and click the MIME Types button.

Every time I run into this problem, I usually have to sit and stare blankly for at least a few minutes before I remember to do this.

Comment: Lol. Yes, I did sit and stare blankly, before thinking, "Eureka! It's the MIME type!" Then I remembered the file extension is .txt, and even double-checked to make sure it was associated correctly.

Comment: Ha ha, yeah, if it's .txt, then you're probably fine by default. Maybe run Process Monitor and filter on w3wp.exe. You might get some clues as to why it's failing to access the file.